# Creating Multiple YAML configurations in Java

Tags: java, yaml, minecraft, bukkit

Plugin for Minecraft(bukkit)

Hello, how do I create multiple configuration files? I'm trying to make it so users can create a config file in their datafolder for a custom TNT that they can create in-game using /actnt create "Name"
Using this command they will create a new config file for their custom TNT
I'm thinking of making a function/method like "generateConfig("Config name" and file to copy from src into their dataFolder)

Example to create a file called fireTNT (Copying from SRC/TNTdefault.yml to dataFolder:
generateConfig(fireTNT, TNTdefault.yml);

Sorry, i'm bad at explaining, but is this possible? And how?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please describe a concrete problem. Do you have a problem with registering a command? Or with writing a function? Or with creating a file in the user's data folder? Or with copying a file? Is it relevant that it is a YAML file (if not, please remove the tag)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the YamlConfiguration Class.

This could look like:

```java
FileConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.load(new File("/path/to/file.yml"));
FileConfiguration config2 = YamlConfiguration.load(new File("/path/to/file2.yml"));
```

Comment: I've done this
`FileConfiguration tntDefault = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(new File(getDataFolder() + "/Custom TNTs/" + args[1] + ".yml"));`


But now this don't work:

`if (file.exists(tntDefault)) {
                                try {
                                    tntDefault.createNewFile();`

Comment: You have only forgotten to put the '!' before the expression.
Your could should look like this:

if(!file.exists()){

try {
file.createNewFile();
}catch(Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: That don't work, it says "'file' has private access in 'org.bukkit.something.something'"